# return a value when an JButton actionperformed event is called

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionevent

I have some problem with `JButton` action events, I have declared a global variable (`boolean tc1`) and a `JButton t1`. When I press the JButton I need to change the value of the boolean variable to 'true'. Can any one help me out? My code goes here.

```
class Tracker extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tracker();    
   }

    public Tracker() {

        JButton tr=new JButton("TRACKER APPLET");
        JButton rf=new JButton("REFRESH");

        boolean tc1=false,tc2=false,tc3=false,tc4=false;
        JButton t1=new JButton(" ");

        t1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                tc1=true;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(tc1);
        //remaining part of the code...
        // here i need to use the value of tc1 for further process..


    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What's not working?

Answer (score 2):

`tc1` must be an instance variable.
You can use a local variable in an another class defined inside the method, unless the local variable is a `final` variable.
Take out the declaration of `tc1` from the `constructor` to the visibility of whole `class`

```
  class Tracker extends JPanel {
  boolean tc1=false,tc2=false,tc3=false,tc4=false;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Tracker();    
  }

public Tracker() {

    JButton tr=new JButton("TRACKER APPLET");
    JButton rf=new JButton("REFRESH");

    
    JButton t1=new JButton(" ");

    t1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            tc1=true;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(tc1);
    //remaining part of the code...
    // here i need to use the value of tc1 for further process..


   }
}
```

I have also encountered this problem already and luckily I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Define click handler:

```
public void onClick(Boolean tc1){
  System.out.println(tc1) ;
  //Write some logic here and use your updated variable
}
```

And then:

```
public Tracker()
{

JButton tr=new JButton("TRACKER APPLET");
JButton rf=new JButton("REFRESH");

boolean tc1=false,tc2=false,tc3=false,tc4=false;
JButton t1=new JButton(" ");

     t1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          tc1 = true ;
          onClick(tc1) ;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of a local method variable in an anonymous inner class (the action listener). You can however change an instance variable of the outer class... so you could just move tc1 to Tracker.

```
class Tracker extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tracker();
    }

    private boolean tc1; // <=== class level instead...

    public Tracker() {

        JButton t1 = new JButton(" ");

        t1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tc1 = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you said that `i have declared a global variable(boolean tc1)`, here tc1 is not a global variable, if you want a global variable then you must declare that variable as `static`.

Then if you want to access that variable on `button click event` then you can write following code:

```
class Tracker extends JPanel
{
    boolean tc1=false,tc2=false,tc3=false,tc4=false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tracker();    
    }
    public Tracker()
    {
        JButton tr=new JButton("TRACKER APPLET");
        JButton rf=new JButton("REFRESH");

        JButton t1=new JButton(" ");

        t1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            tc1=true;
            getValue();
        }
        });
    }
    public void getValue()
    {
        System.out.println("values is: "+ tc1);
    }
}
```