# Method that returns text from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I have a static method in which I would like to return a String from a `JTextField`. I would like it to act like `Scanner`'s `nextLong()`, when the method is called, the rest of the program stalls until input. Here's my code, with my attempt on how to do this.

```
String y;

JTextField a = new JTextField(7);
a.setFont(silkScreen);
a.setForeground(Color.white);
a.setBackground(Color.black);
a.setAlignmentX(JTextField.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
a.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
a.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (a.getText().length() >= 9) { // limit textfield to 9 characters
            e.consume();
        }
    }
});
a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        y = a.getText();
    }
});

panel.add(a);
frame.add(panel);

frame.pack();
frame.setSize(640 / 2, 480 / 2);
frame.setVisible(true);
return y;
```

But, Java spits out this error:

> Local variable y defined in an enclosing scope must be final or
>   effectively final

Comment: *"Java spits out this error:"* As a programmer, you will see lots of compiler errors like that, and it is important to be able to figure out most of them on your own. So as a start to that, what did your search related to that error message reveal?

Comment: Read this, it may give you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423028/java-local-variable-visibility-in-anonymous-inner-classes-why-is-final-keywo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with local variable scope. How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894509/problems-with-local-variable-scope-how-to-solve-it)

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909401/return-a-value-when-an-jbutton-actionperformed-event-is-called

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener` for this, it won't be triggered by calling `setText` or pasting text into the field, use a `DocumentFilter` instead